Create dax query in query editor to split table into multiple tables
Given this type of table structure:
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00

I need to create two more tables that look like this:
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Buy    01/01/24     10.00

AND
Counterparty  Product  Deal  Date          Value
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
foo           bar      Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00
fizz          buzz     Sell   01/01/24     10.00

I am new to power bi, but In the query editor how can I create two more tables based on some condition like shown above? I also need to preserve the main table. Is something like this possible in query editor?
Edit: I can run a python script using pandas like this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df = df[df['DealType'].eq('Buy/Sell')]

But I want to know the DAX equivalent to this

Are you sure you want the query editor (not available in your model and used for ad hoc queries)? If so, it is the following:
EVALUATE
FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Deal] = "Buy")

If you want a table in your model, then create a calculated table as
FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Deal] = "Buy")


I am still navigating my way through power bi so I wasn't sure where to do it, but the second option was what I was looking for thank you!
